# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$value' in 'field list''

Tags: php, pdo

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$password) ; 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $formInfo = array('fname','lname','email','password','gender') ;
    $entry = array() ;
    foreach($formInfo as $data) {

     $entry[$data] = $_POST[$data]; 

     }
    //print_r($entry); 


    $salt = Hash::gen_salt() ;
    $sqlcollum = array(
                'First_name'=> $entry['fname'] ,
                'Last_name' => $entry['lname'] ,
                'email'     => $entry['email'] ,
                'password'  => Hash::gen_password($entry['password'],$salt) ,
                'salt'      => $salt,
                'gender'    => $entry['gender'] ,
                'date'      => date('Y-m-d H:i'),
                'groups'    => '1'
             ) ;
    $sqlKeys = array_keys($sqlcollum) ;
    $sqlValues = array_values($sqlcollum) ;
    $keys = "'".implode("','", $sqlKeys)."'" ;
    $value = "'".implode("','", $sqlValues)."'" ;
    //echo $keys."<br/>" ;
    //echo $value."<br/>" ;


    $db->beginTransaction() ;

    $insert = $db->query('INSERT INTO register ($keys) VALUES ($value)') ;

    if($insert) {
        echo "true" ;
    } else {
        $db->errorCode() ;
        echo "false" ;
    }
   $db->commit() ;


 } catch(PDOExpection $e) { 
    $db->rollback() ;
    die($e->getMessage()) ;
}
```

Why do I get this error?

> error::Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$value' in 'field list'' in register.php:46

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this .

```
 $keys = implode(",",$sqlKeys) ;
```

this working .

Comment: This wasn't an issue.

Comment: OK, now I see that it is correct and all other answers are wrong. Your answer would be much more useful if you add an explanation why you made this change.

Comment: @Naktibalda    i can't give explanation for answer , same problem occur to me . but in most place i see that no need of single quote  for column name so  i try it and work .for example [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) , [mysqltutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-insert-data-into-mysql-table/)

Comment: I will help:  Wrong type of quotes was used for column names, column names must be unquoted or quoted with backticks - `. And your answer was only partial (other answers were partial too) - there was another issue with quotes around INSERT statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
$insert = $db->query('INSERT INTO register ($keys) VALUES ($value)');
```

should be

```
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO register ('$keys') VALUES ('$value')");
```

or

```
$insert = $db->query('INSERT INTO register ('.$keys.') VALUES ('.$value.')');
```

or

```
$insert = $db->query(sprintf('INSERT INTO register (%s) VALUES (%s)', $keys, $value));
```

The reason your code isn't working is that for PHP `$keys` and `$value`  inserted into the string as you have done, are simply a part of the string itself, so values aren't substituted with variable's ones.

Comment: @DonCallisto  now error is 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: mode must be an integer' in register.php

Comment: @leecarter isn't your connection string suffering from same problem? Try to substitute it with `$db = new PDO('mysql:host="$host";dbname="$dbname"',$user,$password);`

Comment: @DonCallisto   your new error no such host as new $db

Comment: @leecarter I suppose your error is elsewhere and we cannot help you anymore. sorry.

Comment: $insert = $db->query('INSERT INTO register ("$keys") VALUES ("$value")'); is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in your code:

1)  There is no need to add extra quotes when you use these in query as a string it this will cover.

Replace:

```
$keys = "'".implode("','", $sqlKeys)."'" ;
$value = "'".implode("','", $sqlValues)."'" ;
```

With:

```
$keys = implode("','", $sqlKeys);
$value = implode("','", $sqlValues);
```

2) Use string variables into quotes:

```
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO register ('$keys') VALUES ('$value')") ;
```