# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$Valuess' in 'field list''

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
 try {
     $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$password) ;

     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


     $sqlcollum = array(
                 'First_name'=> 'gaurav',
                 'Last_name' => 'sundaram',

              ) ;
     $Keys = array_keys($sqlcollum) ;
     $Valuess = array_values($sqlcollum) ;
     $Valuess = "'".implode("'", $Valuess)."'" ;


     $db->beginTransaction() ;
    $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO register ($Keys) VALUES ($Valuess)') ;
    $insert->execute() ;
;
    if($insert) {
        echo "true" ;
    } else {
        $db->errorCode() ;
        echo "false" ;
    }
   $db->commit() ;


 } catch(PDOExpection $e) { 
    $db->rollback() ;
    die($e->getMessage()) ;

}
```

error is SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$Valuess' in 'field list'' in  try2.php:31. how shpuld i type insert statement correctly

Comment: put insert query in double quote (")

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630140/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-value-in-field-list/34630192#34630192

Comment: @DonCallisto  there are  no correct answer

Comment: @gaurav Use double quotes `"` to pass variables. Also, look into using prepared statements (or you'll risk [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)).

Comment: @Qirel after double quotes error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Comment: What does `echo "INSERT INTO register ($Keys) VALUES ($Valuess)";` produce? (It might be that your variables produce an invalid query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the string inside ""

```
$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO register ($Keys) VALUES ($Valuess)")
```

Because inside '' variable behave like string but inside "" variables values are fetched.

Also change

```
 $Valuess = "'".implode("','", $Valuess)."'" ;
```

Values must be imploded with comma like 'gaurav','sundaram'

Comment: new error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Comment: you are right but there also need this  ` $keys = implode(",", Keys) ;`

Answer (score 0):

Use bindParam instead - an example from the PHP docs:

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: for security concern which is best array or BindParam with